# Grunt Task - Movig files from one folder to another

Tags: file, gruntjs, copy, paste

I have problem with writing native functino that will copy my files from one directory to another and exclude some files and directories in process.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
   grunt.initConfig({
        //....
        copy: {
            prod: {
                src: ["./src/*"],
                dest: ["build/"]
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is my custom Task Load:

```
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('copy', function(){
        var src = grunt.config.get('copy.src'),
            dest = grunt.config.get('copy.dest'),
            grunt.file.copy(src, dest);
    });
```

I get this error in my console:

> Warning: Task "copy" not found.

I though this is native grunt functionality regarging to:
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file

Then my prod look like this:

```
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["concat", "uglify", "htmlmin", "imagemin", "copy"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not a native grunt function after all. You can install "copy" and there is no need to write a custom Task Load function.

Install copy from:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-copy --save-dev
```

More about the plugin at:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

I reconfigured my Copy Task in the init to this:

```
        copy: {
            prod: {
                files: [
                    {expand: true, src: ['./src/**'], dest: 'build/'}
                ]
            }
        }
```

And included

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
```

That's all. It works now.